How to solve "Duplicated samples have been found in X" error for DBCV metric
I'm trying to compute the DBCV metric (provided by "git+https://github.com/FelSiq/DBCV") on density-based clusters from a dataset similar to the one shown here:

The calculation is performed with the following code:
dbcv_score = dbcv(X, labels)

where X represents the dataset, and labels are the labels produced by the DBSCAN algorithm.
I've already tried removing duplicates from X, but the same error persists:
5 frames
ValueError: Duplicated samples have been found in X.
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/dbcv/core.py in _check_duplicated_samples(X, threshold)
ValueError: Duplicated samples have been found in X.
How can I resolve this issue?
